# Setting up service to execute tasks in web clustered environment

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, celery, amazon-sqs

I am looking for ways to reliably execute a task (just one time at certain date/time) in web clustered environment: for example to send an email reminder to user after 7 days since initial registration. I am aware of ways to accomplish that using cron/django-cron/django-chronograph etc, but everything I found so far seem to be designed for single-server scenario.

I want to avoid sending duplicate reminders as a result of same job running on multiple servers and so far it seems like rolling up your own database-based solution with locking, expiration timeouts etc in the web cluster is really the only option. Are there any existing solutions for this that would work well in web clustered environment?

Comment: This is *exactly* what Celery is for, so given you already know about it I don't understand your question.

Comment: I am currently using Celery (with Amazon SQS as message broker) for other tasks and unless I am missing something, there isn't a way in Celery to run a task at particular point of time. Also, there are two issues with using SQS in this scernario: 1) Maximum message retention period in SQS is 14 days 2) SQS doesn't guarantee that the message will only be delivered once.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Celery Periodic Task](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html).

```
from datetime import timedelta

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=30),
        'args': (16, 16)
    },
}

CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
```